# Index function in Excel not working

Tags: excel

I am trying to use the index function in Excel, but seems like I am doing it wrong !

What am I trying to do is:

I have values names in a column, like Name1, Name2, Name 3. Now I want to randomly put those names in a other column, so I have tried like that:

```
= INDEX(AD2;AD11; RANDBETWEEN(1;10)) // AD is the column and I want to take the value from AD2 to AD11
```

but it is not working, do anyone knows any answer to that solution !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small typo:

```
= INDEX(AD2:AD11; RANDBETWEEN(1;10))
```

There should be a `:` in the range not a `;`

Comment: thanks a lot :) , May I ask you something, how can I change the whole rows values, means if I have 700 rows how can I change them all at once ! Because right now it is changing just for 1 single rows

Comment: Do you mean you want a whole column that randomizes column AD?    You can copy this formula down by making the references absolute: `= INDEX($AD$2:$AD$11; RANDBETWEEN($1;$10))`,  This will give you a column of randomized names, but it will have duplicates from Column AD.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you are simply awesome :)